# Use TFSSecurity to Change Permissions

Tags: tfs, cmd, tfs-security

I want to change the permissions associated with a group via the TFSSecurity tool.

Apparently, the following command sets the "View instance-level information" permission:

```
>tfssecurity /a+ Server FrameworkGlobalSecurity GenericRead sid:[Group SID] ALLOW /server:[Server URI]
```

This works fine - but obviously how do I set the levels for other permissions?  I assume that "FrameworkGlobalSecurity" is the part of this command that maps to "View instance-level information", but what about the other types of permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was looking for the same thing as you were and the following resource helped me finally to do so:
[Add permissions with TFSSecurity–The ultimate reference](http://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/)

But let's start from scratch:

1. [First check what you want to do with TFSSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252504.aspx)
2. [Second check the permission you want to add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx)
3. [Third check the Token you need to do so with the provided link above](http://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/)